# Using Office Name.dll as a COM object in .NET

Tags: com, ms-office, contacts

I'm trying to use MS Office Name.dll as a COM object.
I found some help in these links to do something like this in web browsers:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms455335(v=office.14).aspx

http://mcgivery.com/displaying-a-users-lync-status-using-namectrl/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2013/03/02/integrate-lync-into-your-intranet-sites-using-the-namectrl-plug-in.aspx

name.dll basically allows me to get presence information from MS Lync and display a contact card.

I was able to successfully create a test Windows Form application that references name.dll. VisualStudio creates an Interop for me and i'm able to use the class NameCtrl.

The project worked fine and my test aplication was able to display the contact card, but only when working with an old version of Office 2010.
When upgrading to Office 2010 SP2, it didnt work anymore. When using Office 2013, it never worked.

I can actually instantiate the object successfully, but the object's property 'PresenceEnable' is always 0, and trying to display the contact card throws an exception "E_ACCESDENIED 0x80070005". In these not-working environments, using the webbrowser (IE/ Firefox) still works fine.

Does anyone know what to do to make it work?
Why did it only work with an old version of Office 2010 and stopped to work with newer releases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to a Microsoft Office Engineer and he told me this dll was not meant to be used that way: it's only meant to be used inside web browsers.